# How to implement set property in testng

Tags: java, selenium, testng

```
    import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class redc {
    public static WebDriver driver=null;
    public static  void startdriver()
    {
    String key="webdriver.gecko.driver";
    String path="C:\\selenium3\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe";
    System.setProperty(key,path);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        }
    @BeforeMethod
    public void call()
    {


    }
    @Test
    public void t1()
    {
        driver.get("https://www.dynamiclevels.com/");
    }
```

I am trying to run this code but constantly getting error

> FAILED: t1 java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   datac.redc.t1(redc.java:25)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

Please help me correct the code. If possible rewrite it in in a way it would work. I am sure i am making same silly mistake i cant catch. :(

Comment: Was `startdriver` called?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2):

```
@BeforeTest
public void setup() {
    String key= "webdriver.gecko.driver";
    String path= "C:\\selenium3\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe";
    System.setProperty(key, path);
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
}
```

and remove static from WebDriver:

```
private WebDriver driver;
```